# Is there a way to rotate logs in AWS ECS through task definition configuration?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, datadog

I'm running datadog agent container in EC2 by configuring task definition in AWS ECS.

But at this time, the huge amount of logs is stored in  /var/lib/docker/containers/**ContainerID**/**ContainerID**.json so that I want to rotate it.

In Docker documents, I saw this [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/).

There are

```
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3"
```

Now I want to config these options through task definition but I don't know the convention of them.
Did anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you put in ECS Task Definition (sample from json version, but in UI also possible to setup), you should be able to configure container logs:

```
"logConfiguration": {
   "logDriver": "json-file",
   "options": {
       "max-size": "10m",
       "max-file": "3"
   }
}
```